# Covert an object to an array in yii2

Tags: arrays, object, yii2

```
    $memberDetails = new MemberSearch();
```

I want to convert the object $memberDetails to an array . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: $arrayValues = $memberDetails->attributes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array helper

```
$memberDetails = new MemberSearch();
$results=ArrayHelper::toArray($memberDetails ,[
'common\models\Member'=>[
    'id',
    'name',
    ...
    ...                    
 ]
] );
```

or for a query, you can convert the result into an array

```
$memberDetails = new MemberSearch();
$dataProvider = $memberDetails->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$myArray= $dataProvider->all()->asArray();
```

Refer [Yii2 ArrayHelper - toArray](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray()-detail)